# Please confirm my answer for this trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry

So I finally figured this out I think. Here is the problem:

If $f(\theta)= cot(\theta)= -2$, find $f( \theta + \pi)$.

So I drew a circle since $-2$ is at about $-115$ degrees I set my point there and then rotated it $180$ degrees in the positive direction which lands me in the second quadrant with a negative cot. Thus, the answer is $-2$ correct?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to solving the problem is to observe
\begin{align}
f(\theta) = \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
f(\theta + \pi) = \frac{\cos(\theta+\pi)}{\sin(\theta+\pi)}.
\end{align}
Now use the angle sum formula for sine and cosine.